# Microorganism preventative solution safe for using on a roof and will last in the sun

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, solutions, surfactants

Information is scarce in the roof cleaning industry and the big guys are making a killing selling chemicals that are harmful to the person using it and everything around the home. I would like to find something safe that I can use to prevent microorganisms from ever popping back up on my customers roofs.

Comment: What chemicals are in the materials sold by the "big guys"?  How unsafe are they?  What degree of safety is important to you?  I ask because it will be impossible to find something 100% safe, i.e., complete without risk.  (Even water can kill you if you use it wrong.)  What kinds of microorganisms do you want to control?  Surely not all of them...just fungi?

Comment: I want it to be safe enough for people and also safe enough for the come household plant. If it has the possibility to kill or damage any plant it will be bad for business.